# Adding elements to std::vector in a repeated way

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I want to copy values from one vector to other one that will be stored in a specific order and the second vector will contain more elements than the first one.

For example:

```
vector<int> temp;
temp.push_back(2);
temp.push_back(0);
temp.push_back(1);
int size1 = temp.size();

int size2 = 4;
vector<int> temp2(size1 * size2);
```

And now I would like to fill *temp2* like that: {2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}.

Is it possible to do this using only algorithms (e.g. fill)?

Comment: Yes, `std::fill()` can be applied to `std::vector` instances.

Comment: By the way your vector construction is wrong; it has 6 elements, not 3.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible using [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) algorithm:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> base{1, 0, 2};
    const int factor = 4;
    std::vector<int> out{};

    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(out), base.size() * factor,
            [&base, counter=0]() mutable {
        return base[counter++ / factor];
    });

    for(const auto i : out) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

This code prints: `1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2`

The key is the lambda used in `std::generate_n`.  It operates on internal counter to know which values, based on `base` vector (and accessed depending on `factor` and `counter` values), to generate.

Comment: Is a single execution of the lambda per target element guaranteed?

Comment: Also this kind of seems like cheating - this is not really the algorithm doing the work, but a custom lambda doing the work, albeit with some language framing. Not saying it's a bad solution but to claim that it means C++ has an algorithm for the OP's use case is a bit of a stretch!

Comment: Regarding your first comment - I believe so, since the guaranteed complexity is "***exactly** `base.size() * factor` invocations of a generator function"*. Regarding your second comment - some algorithms are designed to work with functors, and if you view it as a more of a functor's, rather than algorithm's, work - that's fine, but it is the very purpose of some algorithms that support functors. If you ask "is there an algorithm where I just specify `factor` and it does the job for me", then the answer is obviously **no**, but that was not the question.

Comment: Well, actually I believe it was the question: _"Is it possible to do this using **only** algorithms (e.g. fill)?"_ Again, though, we can use some algorithms as building blocks to construct a decent solution, as you've shown.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is quite a specific use case, but you can trivially implement it yourself.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> Elongate(const std::vector<int>& src, const size_t factor)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    result.reserve(src.size() * factor);

    for (const auto& el : src)
       result.insert(result.end(), factor, el);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> temp{2, 0, 1};
   std::vector<int> real = Elongate(temp, 4);

   for (const auto& el : real)
       std::cerr << el << ' ';
   std::cerr << '\n';
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6bcf61fb22d1cbf))

Comment: `Elongate` is somewhat of an odd choice, for a name.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Elongate is an English word meaning "to stretch", which is exactly what this does.